Ubuntu proxy ARP limit subnet
I have a physical server that works as a hypervisor with several VDS. For virtual network interfaces, I enabled proxy_arp, but it resolves absolutely any IP address. For example, I can add the following route to the virtual server: ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 dev eth0. tcpdump on the hypervisor says that the hypervisor's MAC address was passed for this IP
01:57:48.528223 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 123.45.67.89, length 46
01:57:48.528225 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 123.45.67.89, length 46
01:57:48.533807 ARP, Reply 8.8.8.8 is-at 0a:00:27:00:00:00, length 28

Is it possible to limit proxy_arp on a specific interface to only work with the 123.45.67.0/24 subnet?

Does your setup require proxy-arp in the first place?
